# Not being paid agreed upon amount and no one is helping me. What do I do?

Tags: salary, internship, human-resources

Currently intern in Ohio, USA. Working for the summer only. Job ends this week. I cannot quit because this is for college credit.

I agreed to work for a stipend and am now am being paid hourly. I am missing a lot of money but no one knows how to help me or direct me to someone that can.

**Question:** How do I get answers? If they don't pay me, what do I do?

Link to previous question. 
[What should I do when not being paid the agreed amount?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95536/what-should-i-do-when-not-being-paid-the-agreed-amount/95695#95695)

Comment: Please don't repost the same question again. Question merged to your original.